# Installing Specific Version of Numpy for Dedupe Error

Tags: python-dedupe

I am new to python and already running into some issues:

To clean some data i wanted to try [dedupe](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe) / [csvdedupe](https://github.com/dedupeio/csvdedupe)

It needed numpy to run, so i installed it (worked without a problem)

```
pip install numpy
pip install dedupe
```

but when i wanted to install it

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.13.1 
(from versions: 1.14.5, 1.15.0rc2) 
No matching distribution found for numpy==1.13.1
```

so i uninstalled numpy and installed the specific version

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install "numpy==1.13.1"
```

and then i got this as a error result:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install "numpy==1.13.1"
Collecting numpy==1.13.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/3a/40967d9f5675fbb097ffec170f59c2ba19fc96373e73ad47c2cae9a30aed/numpy-1.13.1.zip
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\WINUSR~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yog0dkax\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-j_8zwj0j\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Running from numpy source directory.

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Der Befehl "svnversion" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
    konnte nicht gefunden werden.
    Der Befehl "svnversion" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
    konnte nicht gefunden werden.
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\windowsuser\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.7\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Inumpy\core\src\private -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -Ic:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_configtest.c /Fo_configtest.obj
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=1 /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\lib\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64" _configtest.obj /OUT:_configtest.exe
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.obj _configtest.exe
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Inumpy\core\src\private -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -Ic:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_configtest.c /Fo_configtest.obj
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\setup.py", line 392, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\setup.py", line 384, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 131, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 62, in run
        r = self.setuptools_run()
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run
        return distutils_install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 47, in run
        old_build.run(self)
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 148, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 159, in build_sources
        self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 294, in build_library_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 377, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 675, in get_mathlib_info
        mlibs = check_mathlib(config_cmd)
      File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 369, in check_mathlib
        if config_cmd.check_func("exp", libraries=libs, decl=True, call=True):
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 338, in check_func
        libraries, library_dirs)
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 246, in try_link
        libraries, library_dirs, lang)
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 155, in _link
        libraries, library_dirs, lang))
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 95, in _wrap_method
        ret = mth(*((self,)+args))
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 138, in _link
        (src, obj) = self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 105, in _compile
        (body, headers, include_dirs, lang))
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 95, in _wrap_method
        ret = mth(*((self,)+args))
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 133, in _compile
        self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 423, in compile
        self.spawn(args)
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 542, in spawn
        return super().spawn(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 89, in <lambda>
        m = lambda self, *args, **kw: func(self, *args, **kw)
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 139, in CCompiler_spawn
        s, o = exec_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\exec_command.py", line 213, in exec_command
        **env)
      File "C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\numpy\distutils\exec_command.py", line 256, in _exec_command
        text, err = proc.communicate()
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 907, in communicate
        stdout = self.stdout.read()
      File "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 75: character maps to <undefined>

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\windowsuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\WINUSR~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yog0dkax\\numpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-j_8zwj0j\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\WINUSR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yog0dkax\numpy\
```

Comment: try `pip install numpy =1.14` I had some issues with`dedupe`, not exactly what you have, however, somewhat relevant because `dedupe` needed `numpy 1.14` for my `python 3x`.

Comment: This unfortunately does not help. I cannot install numpy because i get a lot of errors (basically the same as described in the question)

Comment: Did you check the version of Visual Studios? Also, did you upgrade your `pip`?